# Sonarqube Integration on Azure Devops - iOS Project

Tags: xcode, azure, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I am trying to integrate Sonarqube onto an iOS project through Azure Pipeline .I have followed the exact steps mentioned here
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/swift-coverage

But I am getting an error saying

```
Error: Error Domain=XCCovErrorDomain Code=0 "Failed to create unarchiver" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create unarchiver, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa71961ce40 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file Metadata.plist couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/runner/work/1/s/tmp.xccovarchive/Metadata.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa71961cd80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}}
```

Can anyone please let me know why this error is showing ,I tried to run the same in local machine and it seems working , and the issue is only on Azure Pipeline.
Looking for some support

Answer (score 0):

I find the same error on link [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/setting-up-code-coverage-report-for-swift-ios-application/62365/5) and [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/xccov-to-sonarqube-generic-sh-fails-with-xcode-12/32671), it could be caused by the coverage data is not correctly generated.

Check the command used according to the Xcode version. In addition, if you are using Microsoft-hosted agent, please check the xcode version on the agent.

[image]